# Delete a record in access from java

Tags: java, sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

How can I delete a record in access from java? I have tried the following but it doesn't seem to work.

```
public void Delete() throws SQLException {
  st.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM [AssignmentDetails] WHERE ([Entry Date],[Project ID],[Employee],[Hours Worked],[Firm Deadline],[Description of Assignment],[Additional Details],[ID]) = ('" + AbstractVariables.getEntryDate() + "','" + AbstractVariables.getProjectID() + "','" + AbstractVariables.getEmployee() + "','" + AbstractVariables.getHoursWorked() + "','" + AbstractVariables.getFirmDeadline() + "','" + AbstractVariables.getDescription() + "','" + AbstractVariables.getAdditionalDetails() + "','"+AbstractVariables.getID() + "')");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try {
    Connection con;
    Statement stmt;
        String url = "jdbc:odbc:GameData.mdb";
    // DATABASE CONNECTION MAGIC :-)
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "user", "password");
    stmt = con.createStatement();
    // DELETE SOME SOME STUDENT DATA (RARELY USED IN GOOD PRACTICE)
    stmt.executeUpdate("delete from students where phone = '000-0000'");

    // DATABASE CLOSE/CLEANUP
    stmt.close();
    con.close();
}
catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a parameterized query using JDBC instead of making it all one big string

PreparedStatement st=connection.createStatement("DELETE FROM [AssignmentDetails] WHERE [Entry Date]=?, [Project ID]=?, etc...);

Then set the parameters on the prepared statement and then execute it